# c++ fix syntax debug with *lec=fopen();

Tags: c++, debugging, syntax, redeclaration

I am working on some C++ code with a friend that know better than I do,
and the code has a bug, I'd like help to fix this, since I couldn't figure out how...

**EDIT**
The compiler stops at line 59 where: `FILE *ecr("result.txt","wt");` is written.

There are many other things to fix, I fixed until 49 (59 now ;) ) I am blocked AGAIN...

Thanks!

**EDIT (again, sorry)**
With the message:

```
C:\Users\ad\Desktop\PYTHON\josh\josh\color\3d\solution_to_array.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
C:\Users\ad\Desktop\PYTHON\josh\josh\color\3d\solution_to_array.cpp|59|error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]|
C:\Users\ad\Desktop\PYTHON\josh\josh\color\3d\solution_to_array.cpp|59|error: cannot convert 'const char*' to 'FILE* {aka _iobuf*}' in initialization|
C:\Users\ad\Desktop\PYTHON\josh\josh\color\3d\solution_to_array.cpp|82|error: expected initializer before '<' token|
C:\Users\ad\Desktop\PYTHON\josh\josh\color\3d\solution_to_array.cpp|82|error: expected ';' before '<' token|
C:\Users\ad\Desktop\PYTHON\josh\josh\color\3d\solution_to_array.cpp|82|error: expected primary-expression before '<' token|
C:\Users\ad\Desktop\PYTHON\josh\josh\color\3d\solution_to_array.cpp|84|error: expected ')' before ']' token|
C:\Users\ad\Desktop\PYTHON\josh\josh\color\3d\solution_to_array.cpp|84|error: expected ')' before ']' token|
C:\Users\ad\Desktop\PYTHON\josh\josh\color\3d\solution_to_array.cpp|84|error: expected primary-expression before ']' token|
C:\Users\ad\Desktop\PYTHON\josh\josh\color\3d\solution_to_array.cpp|84|error: expected ';' before ']' token|
||=== Build finished: 9 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds) ===|
```

If somebody could figure how to fix this, that would be great!

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;


int main() {

int COL = 0;
int LIN = 0;

cout << endl << "columns?" << endl;
cin  >> COL;
cout << "lines?" << endl;
cin  >> LIN;

int CELL = LIN*COL;

cout << CELL << " cells" << endl;

//1- reading the file priority.csv
char Coul[COL][LIN];
for (int i=0; i<COL; i++) Coul[i][0]='\0';

FILE *lec=fopen("priority.csv","rt");

if (lec == NULL) {
        printf("Error");
        return(0);
}

char ligne[120];
int N;

for (int i=0; i<COL; i++)
{
  char nom[8];
  fgets(ligne,15,lec);
  sscanf(ligne,"%d,%s",&N,nom);
  if (N == i) strcpy(Coul[i], nom);

  else {printf("Error");
  break;
  }
}

fclose(lec);

//2- reading the file solution.txt and writing the result.
lec=fopen("solution.txt","rt"); // FIXED HERE

if (lec == NULL) {printf("Error");
    return(0);
    }

FILE *ecr=fopen("result.txt","wt"); //STOPS HERE
for (int i=1; i<CELL; i++)
{
  char c[4][8];  // 4 color names
  float v[4]; // 4 values
  fgets(ligne,119,lec);
  sscanf(ligne,"%d,%s,%f,%s,%f,%s,%f,%s,%f",
              &N, c[0], &v[0], c[1], &v[1], c[2], &v[2], c[3], &v[3]);
  if (N == i)
  {
    if (strlen(c[0]) == 0)  // la ligne est vide
    {
      fprintf(ecr,"%d ",i);
      for (int i=0; i<COL; i++) fprintf(ecr,"0 ");
      fprintf(ecr,"\n");
    }
    else
    {
      fprintf(ecr,"%d ",i);
      int r[4];
// we search the rang of c[ordre]
      for (int ordre=0; ordre<4; ordre++)
      {
        for (int ir=0, ir<COL; ir++)
        {
          if (strcmp(c(ordre], Coul[ir]) == 0) r[ordre]=ir;
        }
      }
      for (int ir=0; ir<r[0]; ir++) fprintf(ecr,"0 ");
      fprintf(ecr,"%d ",v[0]);
      for (int ir=r[0]+1; ir<r[1]; ir++) fprintf(ecr,"0 ");
      fprintf(ecr,"%d ",v[1]);
      for (int ir=r[1]+1; ir<r[2]; ir++) fprintf(ecr,"0 ");
      fprintf(ecr,"%d ",v[2]);
      for (int ir=r[2]+1; ir<r[3]; ir++) fprintf(ecr,"0 ");
      fprintf(ecr,"%d ",v[3]);
      for (int ir=r[3]+1; ir<57; ir++) fprintf(ecr,"0 ");
      fprintf(ecr,"\n");
    }
  }
  else {printf("Error"); break;}
}
fclose (ecr);
fclose(lec);
}
```

Comment: @H2CO3 Oh, come on and stop it... Who cares if the variables have french names?? Apart from that you can read them,so what???

Comment: @bash.d ***Very-very-very hard to read,*** even though I speak French. I'm (and everyone else) is just so used to English variable names. (And if one doesn't *actually* know what the variable names mean, one will have a hard time figuring out the meaning of the code...)

Comment: So, if you are a coder/programmer/whatever you should be able to cope with that... You are one smart guy, aren't you?

Comment: @bash.d now you're acting like it doesn't matter _at all_ which language is used, which is just not true

Comment: @bash.d "Should", but not "want". This is the same thing as indentation. If I see a question without indentation and whitespace, I have no intention to dig through it by any means, although most certainly I could, technically.

Comment: Does it state anywhere in the FAQ/rules to exclusively use English names for variables?? I agree with indentation and whitespace, though!

Comment: @bash.d Not specifically, but the "We are an English-only site" part involves this too AFAIK (for the reasons explained above).

Comment: Indent your code, and write documenting comments in it. It's barely legible ATM. No wonder you're struggling to debug it.

Comment: Can you stop changing the question as we fix each bug for you, this will read like mad nonsense once we finally get it compiling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lec` seems to be declared twice, so the second call should be

```
lec=fopen("solution.txt","rt");
```

since you already have `FILE* lec` above

Comment: Also `FILE *ecr("result.txt","wt");` isn't valid.  There needs to be an fopen in there.

Comment: @dunc123 good point. Makes me wonder how the OP ever got to this code.

Comment: It does say "There are many other things to fix" but the question seemed to be about just that one thing. It might resurface as another question when this is fixed though.

Comment: Thank you, that was it, however doctorlove is right, I get a new error line 59, with this: `FILE *ecr("result.txt","wt");` what should I use to replace `FILE *ecr`?? Thanks so much

Comment: @adrienlucca.wordpress.com as dunc123 has already told you, the fopen is missing in that line.

Answer (score 3):

If you are confronted with several errors it's sometimes worth looking at nearby ones too to see if they help.

```
..._to_array.cpp|53|error: redeclaration of 'FILE* lec'|
..._to_array.cpp|28|error: 'FILE* lec' previously declared here|
```

So, it thinks you have redeclared something. It's right.

```
FILE *lec=fopen("priority.csv","rt");
//...
FILE *lec=fopen("solution.txt","rt");
```

You can change this to

```
FILE *lec=fopen("priority.csv","rt");
//...
lec=fopen("solution.txt","rt");
```

**You might want to consider splitting this long function into some smaller ones, then you are more likely to spot mistakes.**

---

**EDIT**

```
 FILE *ecr("result.txt","wt");
```

is probably meant to be opening a file, as your previous lines did:

```
 FILE *ecr=fopen("result.txt","wt");
```

---

**EDIT**
So, now you fixed that

```
for (int ir=0, ir<COL; ir++)
```

=>

```
for (int ir=0; ir<COL; ir++) //semicolon not comma
//           ^^
```

Next

```
if (strcmp(c(ordre], Coul[ir]) == 0) r[ordre]=ir;
```

=>

```
if (strcmp(c[ordre], Coul[ir]) == 0) r[ordre]=ir; // [ not (
//          ^^
```

That should do it. I dare not run it though - it's not exception safe. 
Don't panic when you get lots of errors - *read them carefully*.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that's the code you're compiling? Line 50 is `fclose(lec)`, which makes no mention of `fopen`.

The rest are a redeclaration of `lec` [53], a missing call to `fopen` [59], a "," (comma) that should be ";" (semicolon) [82], and a "(" that should be "[" [84].